# How Convert packages to units

Tags: java, decimal, converters

I have a question, I'm programming in Java if I have a decimal "3.02" (this is equivalent to 3 packages (1 package = 10 units) and 2 units) and want to convert to "32" (this is equivalent to 32 units ). Does anyone know how to do it? There is a feature that allows java?

Comment: You will problably have to develop a class to deal with this logic yourself.

Comment: `double d = 3.02; int units = (((int) d) * 10) + (int) ((d - (int) d) * 100);`

Comment: great Thanks to  all, the answers solves my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 3 represent the units and the decimal part is 02 then your math is not coherent as it must, since you need 10 units to increment 1 package, I will expected that 3.2 represents 3 packages and 2 units

anyways a code snipped that can solve your math can be:

```
double totalToConvert = 3.02;
        int totalAsInteger = (int) totalToConvert;
        System.out.println(totalAsInteger);
        int decimalPart = (int)((double)(totalToConvert-totalAsInteger)*100);
        int total = totalAsInteger*10 +decimalPart;
        System.out.println(total

);
```

Comment: great Thanks to  all, the answers solves my problem